# Appending Link To Head Of Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, fancybox

I want to append  element To head of an Iframe (fancybox)

there is a strange problem : when I use Firefox to Breakpoint on line of code that append element to Head it  works correctly but when I run site  normally without firebug it does not work;

I am using fancybox 1.3.4 and the code run in onComplete event

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
cssLink.href = "/themes/furniture/css/test.css"; 
cssLink .rel = "stylesheet"; 
cssLink .type = "text/css"; 


var f123= document.getElementById('fancybox-frame');

var d123= f123.contentDocument || f123.contentWindow.document;

d123.head.appendChild(cssLink);
```

UPDATE

I also try this code

```
var $head = $("#fancybox-frame").contents().find("head");                
$head.append($("<link/>", 
{ rel: "stylesheet", href: "/themes/furniture/css/test.css", type: "text/css" } ));
```

but it does not work either

Tnx

Comment: `I want to append element To head of an Iframe` that's good, but where is your code? http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: Ok. I insert code . the code works correctly when I use breakpoint on firebug but not append </link> child when run site normally

Comment: even though you use are using onComplete, have you tried using a timeout? This seems like a racing condition to me - how about other browsers? If it's just a FireFox issue, use an additional `setTimeout(...,50)` after the onComplete and see if that works. (it's ugly, but if it works I'd go with it)

Comment: and what is the code you use to insert into fancybox iframe (show your onComplete init)

Comment: BTW, working with iframes, for security reasons you should consider [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: the iframe exists in same Orgin  : Same Protocol Same Domain Same Port

Comment: The problem exists in IE10, Chrome , Firefox

Comment: My JavaScript Code Link : [jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js](http://zoop.ir/js/jquery/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js)      @JFK

Comment: I Try setTimeout But does not work .

Comment: @JFK
I try other code and attach inline style to body tag . the style (for example background-color)applied for split second and suddenly something reset it , i think my problem is similar to this unanswered Topic                                                     [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438439/fancybox-onstart-oncomplete-status-not-working)                                                             [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fancybox/kfj8Aar1aRY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to be a racing condition indeed (as pointed out by [olsn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518765/olsn) in his comment) between loading the iframe and finding elements inside of it, which fails if the second occurs first ;)

As a workaround, you could use the `.load()` method to wait for the `iframe` to be completely loaded before trying to `append` the stylesheet to the `<head>` section.

This code should do the trick :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        "type": "iframe",
        "onComplete": function () {
            var $style = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/furniture/css/test.css" type="text/css" />';
            $("#fancybox-frame").load(function () {
                $(this).contents().find("head").append($style);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Note** : this is for fancybox v1.3.4. Fortunately v2.x includes more flexible public methods than v1.3.4 to circumvent this issue, like `afterLoad` and `beforeShow`

Also notice that `setTimeout()` will work too, but it renders oddly.

Comment: Tnx .try it but when debug with firebug the code inside load() does not execute. just Skip over it.