# Add CSS sheet to iframe on load with screen size condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, fancybox

I have a page that loads an iframe (fancybox). I would like to be able to insert an additional CSS file based on a jquery condition. Something like below:

```
if ($(window).width() > 1220) {

    var lightbox_stylesheet = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css" type="text/css" />';

    $('head').append(lightbox_stylesheet);
};
```

I have tried doing this on document.ready but that did not work. Does anyone know how to get the iframe to load this CSS file?

Comment: Do you want to insert the css inside the iframe? ... do you have control over the iframed page? .... is the iframed page on the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: Yes inside the iframe. The rest of the site is using a media query but that does not work in the iframe. Using Fancyapps.com/fancybox. They are on the same domain

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/16246501/1055987 if that helps. Make sure you use the proper API options and callbacks depending on the version you are using.